# Setting initialState in reducer asynchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a react app that I am trying to generate routes based on data that is called from redis cache.

I am using https://github.com/ayroblu/ssr-create-react-app-v2

I have a route component which loops through this.props.pages and creates the routes like so:

```
class Routes extends Component {

  getRoutes(){
    let container = null;
    const routes = []

    /**
     *  We use a switch statement because the Routes component 
     *  attribute wont take a string so we need to call
     *  the object that we import i.e. HomePage
     */ 
    forEach(this.props.pages, page => {
      switch(page.template){
        case 'home':
          container = HomePage 
          break;
        case 'about':
          container = AboutPage 
          break;
        default:
          throw new Error("No page container matching page's template")
          return;
      }

      routes.push(<Route path={`${page.path}`} component={container} key={key}/>)
    })

    return routes;

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        {this.getRoutes()}
        <Route component={NoMatch}/>
        }
      </Switch>
    )
  }
}
```

I have a page reducer which fetches the page data for the routes asynchronously from the redis cache which looks like this:

```
import { SET, RESET } from '../types/page'
import getInitialState from './../../server/initialState'

async function getInitialStateFromCache() {
    const initialState = await getInitialState();

    const {pages} = initialState[0]

    return pages
}

const initialState = getInitialStateFromCache()


export default function reducer(state=initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET:
      return Object.assign({}, state, action.payload)
    case RESET:
      return {...initialState}
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

When the first render is called in my route component, `this.props.pages` is undefined so the requested page 404's but then the second render in the client, it appears. This means that when I view page source, the content hasn't been server side rendered.

How can I delay the first render so that `this.props.pages` is defined when I need it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I delay the first render so that this.props.pages is defined when I need it?

Lots of ways to do it. One way is to not call `ReactDOM.render` immediately. Instead:

- have an `index.html` that shows a loader statically
- App entry point loads data
- Once data is loaded you call `ReactDOM.render`.